# Openlayers permalink not working

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

Basically I have a permalink which contains the co-ordinates of a temporary layer when I enter this permalink into the browser the layer shoes and then goes. I used use a vector layer the permalink used to work fine but then I rasterized the layer after doing that the layer does not work. The permalink which contains the layer  looks something like this:

r=POLYGON((15523179.169885%20-4076448.6241544%2C15482208.92273%20-4058715.2335947%2C15490464.121784%20-4097545.2439582%2C15523179.169885%20-4076448.6241544)).

After rasterizing the layer I store the layer in the database before it was simple a  vector layer.

I am using geoserver, openlayers and javascript. The permalink is created using Jquery.

I am not sure who to make the layer show permanently when the user enters the permalink into the browser